# should I leave debug conditions in SSIS script componenets or visual studio for apps

Tags: ssis, debugging

When I write larger scripts in both t-sql and script components, I usually put in a boolean called debug which I can pass or set to as true that will pop up or drop debug information. For Tsql, I know it over head is negligible but is this the same in SSIS script components or VS for apps environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leave it in - I'm finding SSIS extremely efficient with regards to script components.